# fatal error C1083

Tags: c++, visual-c++, testing, compiler-errors, cppunit

I get a compiler error that I can't seem to figure out how to fix. Yes I know it's a stupid one but I can't seem to stop it. I've added the includes to VC++ directories in the IDE options. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the error:

> Error  1   fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cppunit/TestFixture.h': No such file or directory c:\...\Application\Test.cpp    5

Comment: Did you add a directory that contains the "cppunit" directory to the list of includes?

Comment: If that file is in "c:/a/b/c/cppunit/TestFixture.h", then the path you need to specify as an include path is "c:/a/b/c". Make sure you have exactly that.

Comment: not in any .h or .cpp files? Where would I add this includes?

Comment: Add it in the options of the IDE or pass it to the compiler in some other way. It is the include path, not an include statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> C:\cppunit-1.12.1\cppunit-1.12.1\include\cppunit is where the file is that it's looking for but I thought that I added that in the visual studio options

In which case this is wrong:

```
 #include "cppunit/TestFixture.h"
```

It should be:

```
 #include "TestFixture.h"
```

Since you already specified the "cppunit" part of the path in the include directories setting.